# Can we Send Data To Multiple JSP pages in Spring?

Tags: spring, jsp, modelandview

I have a method in my controller say **demo**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/demo")
public ModelAndView demo("some parameters..")
{
 .
 .
 .
 .
 return new ModelAndView("newPage","Message","Welcome to new Page");
{
```

This will send the data to the "newPage". now my question is, can I send the same data to one more page? Does ModelAndView allows it? Every Advice is Appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can use session.setAttribute("yourKaye",yourData); and use session.getAttribute("yourKey"); to get on any jsp page.

Comment: @Sudhir Ojha Thanks for the help, Your solution will work but it will require me to write Java code on jsp page which I Can't do. Can you suggest me a solution using ModelAndView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelAndView pass data to **Page** scope. So Model And View can't send data to other pages.
So you should use **Session** scope or **Application** scope to pass data to other pages.

Session -> `session.setAttribute("key",data);`

Application -> `context.setAttribute("key",data);`

[Servlet Scopes](https://www.javajee.com/application-request-session-and-page-scopes-in-servlets-and-jsps)